# Repairing the Visual Studio 2012 C# compiler after an update?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, updates

I'm attempting to compile C# form and console applications in Visual Studio 2012 Professional (on a Windows 7 home premium operating system). Each time I attempt to upgrade, the compilation process appears to be corrupted by the update. There are errors during compilation that tell me that visual studio is unable to finish building.  The errors shown did not lead to any useful results in my search.  The last error given after running update 4 is "app.config is invalid".

The following attempts did not fix the issue:  running windows update (and resetting it when it got stuck), repairing the visual installation when instructed to after updates, updating and/or cleaning and then reupdating the .net platform.

I first tried to update using several updates, one after the other, without testing the condition after each update.  Later, I found that the problem existed after each update (when I errantly thought that subsequent updates would fix the problem - they did not).  Each time I was able to start Visual Studio and load my applications, but unable to compile.

Ultimately, the only solution that worked for me was to either (1) do a system restore to the base version restore point, or (2) to uninstall the program and then reinstall the base version (making sure to hide all subsequent windows updates related to Visual Studio).

Is there a way to repair/troubleshoot the c# compiler after updates?

Comment: Never heard of such problems I am using VS 2013 with the most recent Windows updates all the time. Maybe you could post the error messages.

Comment: After starting to compile, Visual Studio says "app.config is invalid".

Comment: UPDATE:  Found out that templates were missing as well (which also threw the app.config error, but when creating a new project this time). This led me to install the visual studio 2012 SDK.  Doing so corrected the template issue, still not updating yet for fear of lost functionality...